# Spring Boot Ajax post form submit with model and thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot controller which returns a view and i wanted to change it by consuming an ajax endpoint, but at the same time get the values from the form with a modelAttribute and then send a list or multiple lists on the page and iterate through those lists with thymeleaf.Is it possible?
Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String search(@ModelAttribute("specification") Specification specification, Model model) {

        List<SearchResultAutovit> list;

        list = scrapper.searchMethod(specification.getPrice,specification.getModel);

        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) { 
            model.addAttribute("msg","Something"); 
        } else { 
            model.addAttribute("listaAutovit", list); 
        }
        return "?";
    }
```

Ajax request:

```
$(".btn.btn-danger").on('click', {function fire_ajax_submit() {
    var str = $(".form-inline.justify-content-center").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        data:str,
        url:"/search",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
           alert("success");
        }
    });

}
```

I don't want to manipulate the page from the ajax succes part because i'm already doing that with thymeleaf when the model is sent to the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you want is to receive a Thymeleaf fragment using an `ajax` request. You can achieve this changing your code for the following and adding a fragment where you will add your attributes. We will create an `html` file called list, where we will have the fragment.

**Thymeleaf fragment**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<th:block th:fragment="list">
    <th:block th:if="${list != null}">
        <th:block th:each="iterator: ${list}">
            <!-- Do something -->
        </th:block>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:if="${msg != null}">
        <p th:text=${msg}></p>
    </th:block>
</th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search")
public String search(@ModelAttribute("specification") Specification specification, Model model) {

    List<SearchResultAutovit> list;

    list = scrapper.searchMethod(specification.getPrice,specification.getModel);

    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) { 
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Error!");
        model.addAttribute("list", list);
    } else { 
        model.addAttribute("list", list);
        model.addAttribute("msg", null);
    }
    return "layouts/list :: list";
}
```

Then on your `ajax` you just need to receive the result and append it to an element.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    data:str,
    url:"/search",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
       $(element).append(result);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering! No, i just want to submit the form and then send some lists to the page, iterate through those lists with thymeleaf and basically return the page with those values from the list...but i want to do it asynchronous so the page won't refresh :(

Comment: Ok now I know what you wanted. I just edited my answer. Now you will returning a Thymeleaf fragment with the required list. Hope it helps now. Also, it is recommended now to use `async:false` with `ajax`.

Comment: I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong now cause when i submit the form it returns the string from the controller

Comment: What are you receiving in that string? You should be receiving a html, with the code I send you.

Comment: i receive the string"layouts/list :: list"

Comment: Ok, I changed a few things in my code. I changed the controller request type and remove the `@ResponseBody` annotations. This is how I normally do it when I need to send fragments through `ajax`. Hope it helps now.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!